# Cant use Mapoverlays in Android.. Keep getting null exception

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I've tried every example i could google, and every solution i could find on both stackoverflow and other sites.. But this i just cant get to work..

Now im using the example from androids own website where i create a seperate class. This is my code:

```
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.win_showmap) ;

    MapView map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.googlemap) ;
    map.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mapController = map.getController() ;
    mapController.setZoom(12);

    int lat = (int)(Double.parseDouble(GlobalClass.pass_lattitude) * 1000000) ;
    int lon = (int)( Double.parseDouble(GlobalClass.pass_longitude) * 1000000);
    GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(lat,lon) ;
    p = point ;
    mapController.animateTo(point) ;
    //---Add a location marker---

    List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
    Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pushpin);
    Mapoverlays itemizedoverlay = new Mapoverlays(drawable);


    OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point, "Hola, Mundo!", "I'm in Mexico City!");

    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
    mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);
```

By using Log.d i can find the crash point that gives null point error, to be the line:
List mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();

My API key works fine, because i can se the map if i remove the 6 lines of mapoverlay code.
Don't know if it means anything, but i get these Logcats when not having the overlay code.

02-03 22:44:05.892: I/MapActivity(2374): Handling network change notification:CONNECTED
02-03 22:44:05.892: E/MapActivity(2374): Couldn't get connection factory client

And if i include the overlay code it crashes and i get the Logcat:
    02-03 22:45:33.183: E/AndroidRuntime(2465): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-03 22:45:33.183: E/AndroidRuntime(2465): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.closebuy.namespace/com.closebuy.namespace.Show_map}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-03 22:45:33.183: E/AndroidRuntime(2465):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
02-03 22:45:33.183: E/AndroidRuntime(2465):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
02-03 22:45:33.183: E/AndroidRuntime(2465):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
02-03 22:45:33.183: E/AndroidRuntime(2465):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
02-03 22:45:33.183: E/AndroidRuntime(2465):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-03 22:45:33.183: E/AndroidRuntime(2465):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-03 22:45:33.183: E/AndroidRuntime(2465):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
02-03 22:45:33.183: E/AndroidRuntime(2465):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-03 22:45:33.183: E/AndroidRuntime(2465):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-03 22:45:33.183: E/AndroidRuntime(2465):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
02-03 22:45:33.183: E/AndroidRuntime(2465):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
02-03 22:45:33.183: E/AndroidRuntime(2465):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-03 22:45:33.183: E/AndroidRuntime(2465): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-03 22:45:33.183: E/AndroidRuntime(2465):     at com.closebuy.namespace.Show_map.onCreate(Show_map.java:48)
02-03 22:45:33.183: E/AndroidRuntime(2465):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
02-03 22:45:33.183: E/AndroidRuntime(2465):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)

I've tried it on emulator and on my Galaxy S2.. Please help, i really wan't this to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> By using Log.d i can find the crash point that gives null point error, to be the line: List mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();

Where are you declaring and initializing the variable `mapView`? The only `MapView` type variable I see initialized is `map`.

```
MapView map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.googlemap) ;
```

So, I would try:

```
List<Overlay> mapOverlays = map.getOverlays();
```

If that still crashes with a null pointer error, then you have no MapView view declared within the `win_showmap.xml` layout.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot the "top":

public class Show_map extends MapActivity {
private MapController mapController;
MapView mapView; 
MapController mc;
GeoPoint p;

Comment: So `mapView` is declared but is not initialized. Did you try to use the variable you did initialize as I wrote?

Comment: Dang i feel foolish now!
I spent 4 hours trying to figure out what was wrong, and then it was because i used a variable from what i'm guessing is one of the first examples i tried. This solved everything. Thanks a million!

Comment: Excellent, best of luck in the rest of your app.

Answer (score 0):

I know there's an error in the documentation for this sample. From memory I think the constructor is just plain wrong. I think it needs to be

```
public HelloItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, Context context) {
        // super(defaultMarker); <<<< REPLACE THIS WITH THE LINE BELOW
        super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
        mContext = context;
    }
```

Comment: Yes i found this one also via another thread in here. Turned out it was a totally different error i had made